# vscode attached to Docker container - module not found

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm running `vscode` debugger inside `Docker` container but it started showing an error:
[image]

That is very strange because when I open python shell in the same `vscode` window and import the same module import works just fine. So I need to find the reason why debugger doesn't see the modules

The full error code:

```
root@854c8a51d1f6:/opt/HonkioServer# python3 entrypoints/api2/docker_entry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entrypoints/api2/docker_entry", line 3, in <module>
    from index import app
  File "/opt/HonkioServer/entrypoints/api2/index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from honkio.db.Application import ApplicationModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'honkio'
root@854c8a51d1f6:/opt/HonkioServer#  cd /opt/HonkioServer ; /usr/bin/env /bin/python3 /root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 39239 -- /opt/HonkioServer/entrypoints/api2/docker_entry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/HonkioServer/entrypoints/api2/docker_entry", line 3, in <module>
    from index import app
  File "/opt/HonkioServer/entrypoints/api2/index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from honkio.db.Application import ApplicationModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'honkio'
```

My debugger config file `launch.json`

```
    {
      "name": "Python: File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "/opt/HonkioServer/entrypoints/api2/docker_entry",
      "justMyCode": true
    }
```

Comment: Chust check the python version you are using for the debugger execution. It has to be the same python version as the one you installed the honkio package.

Comment: `honkio` is a local python file and I set python version at the bottom of vscode as I did before when this script was running normally

Comment: It seems that the honkio folder isn't in the path of the python debugger execution. Where is the folder honkio located?

Comment: it is located two levels higher than `docker_entry` file

Comment: Can you show your directory structure and provide your `launch.json` for the recurrence of the problem? If you run the file directly without using debug, is it successful to run the file?

Comment: I pulled original branch from repo and created mine from scratch and it worked well until I pushed newly created branch to server. I don't understand why this happens

Comment: I updated dscription and added `launch.json` file

Comment: It looks like if I change particular file the process crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the source of this issue - it was in the file that directly imported to `docker-entry` file and modules from project directories were imported in a strange way:

```
# This line adds to modules imports that added below cd two levels up
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/../..")

import honkio
```

However, right after I change this file in `vs code`, formatter changed lines order automatically placing that line at the bottom of all the other imports. Therefore file imports break and it shows `module not found error`